How to use the existing services to deploy PieCloudDB
I want to deploy a PieCloudDB cluster. I already have S3, PostgreSQL, and FoundationDB services. Can I use these existing services to deploy PieCloudDB Database?(Avoid deploying redundant services.) If so, how should I modify the configuration file?

1.Edit the s3_config.yaml file, add the correct S3 endpoint, access ID, and secret key. If using an existing external bucket, set the use_existing_bucket to true.
s3:
  region: us-east-1
  endpoint: 172.168.78.101:9000
  access_key_id: minioadmin
  secret_access_key: minioadmin
  force_path_style: true
  use_existing_bucket: false
  bucket_name: ""
s3_lifecycle:
  access_key_id: minioadmin
  secret_access_key: minioadmin
  bucket_name: ""
s3_persist:
  access_key_id: minioadmin
  secret_access_key: minioadmin
  bucket_name: ""

2.Edit the pg_config.yaml file, add the correct connection information for PostgreSQL, and create the required database in the target PG service in advance.
postgres:
  dbname: dbpiebackend
  host: dbhost_address
  password: 1
  port: 5432
  user: postgres
  uc_host: postgres.openpie
  uc_user: postgres
  uc_password: 1
  uc_dbname: dbusercenter
  uc_port: 5432
  ops_host: postgres.openpie
  ops_user: postgres
  ops_password: 1
  ops_dbname: dbpieoperation
  ops_port: 5432

3.Obtain the FoundationDB address and edit the fdb_config.yaml file. Log in to the server where the FoundationDB service is deployed and find the fdb.cluster file.
cat fdb.cluster
fdb_connect: docker:docker@pie-fdb.openpie:4500

4.Deploy PieCloudDB
./deploy -s s3_config.yaml -p pg_config.yaml -f fdb_config.yaml -e k8s_master_ip

